# C++20 coroutine，the caller function is not finished(looks like suspended) after co_return

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

Here are the codes for testing coroutines of c++20，running on https://godbolt.org/ with “x86_64 gcc (coroutines)” compiler, Unfortunately, the output is strange:the last message in main function is not printed: the main function looks like being suspended.

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<coroutine>
using namespace std;

struct future_type{
    struct promise_type{
    int ret_val;
    using co_handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    promise_type(){
        std::cout<<"promise_type constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~promise_type(){
        std::cout<<"promise_type destructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    auto get_return_object(){
        std::cout<<"get_return_object"<<std::endl;
        return co_handle_type::from_promise(*this);
    }
    auto initial_suspend(){
        std::cout<<"initial_suspend"<<std::endl;
        return std::suspend_always();
    }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept(true) {
        std::cout<<"final_suspend"<<std::endl;
        return std::suspend_never();
    }
    void return_value(int val){
        std::cout<<"return_value : "<<val<<std::endl;
        ret_val = val;
    }
    void unhandled_exception(){
        std::cout<<"unhandled_exception"<<std::endl;
        std::terminate();
    }
    auto yield_value(int val){
        std::cout<<"yield_value : "<<val<<std::endl;
        ret_val = val;
        return std::suspend_always();
    }
};
    using co_handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    future_type(co_handle_type co_handle){
        std::cout<<"future_type constructor"<<std::endl;
        co_handle_ = co_handle;
    }
    ~future_type(){
        std::cout<<"future_type destructor"<<std::endl;
        co_handle_.destroy();
    }
    future_type(const future_type&) = delete;
    future_type(future_type&&) = delete;

    bool resume(){
        if(!co_handle_.done()){
            co_handle_.resume();
        }
        return !co_handle_.done();
    }
    bool await_ready() { 
        return false; 
    }
    bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {
        resume();
        return false;
    }
    auto await_resume() {
        return co_handle_.promise().ret_val;
    }

    co_handle_type co_handle_;
};

future_type three_step_coroutine(){
    std::cout<<"three_step_coroutine begin"<<std::endl;
    co_yield 222;
    std::cout<<"three_step_coroutine running"<<std::endl;
    co_yield 333;
    std::cout<<"three_step_coroutine end"<<std::endl;
    co_return 444;
}

struct void_future{
struct promise_type{
    using co_handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;
    promise_type(){
        std::cout<<"promise_type constructor void"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~promise_type(){
        std::cout<<"promise_type destructor void"<<std::endl;
    }
    auto get_return_object(){
        std::cout<<"get_return_object void"<<std::endl;
        return co_handle_type::from_promise(*this);
    }
    auto initial_suspend(){
        std::cout<<"initial_suspend void"<<std::endl;
        return std::suspend_always();
    }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept(true) {
        std::cout<<"final_suspend void"<<std::endl;
        return std::suspend_never();
    }
    void unhandled_exception(){
        std::cout<<"unhandled_exception void"<<std::endl;
        std::terminate();
    }
    void return_void(){
        std::cout<<"return_void void: "<<std::endl;
    }
};
    using co_handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

    void_future(co_handle_type co_handle){
        std::cout<<"void_future constructor"<<std::endl;
        co_handle_ = co_handle;
    }
    ~void_future(){
        std::cout<<"void_future destructor"<<std::endl;
        co_handle_.destroy();
    }
    void_future(const void_future&) = delete;
    void_future(void_future&&) = delete;

    bool resume(){
        if(!co_handle_.done()){
            co_handle_.resume();
        }
        return !co_handle_.done();
    }

    co_handle_type co_handle_;
};
void_future call_coroutine(){
    auto future = three_step_coroutine();
    std::cout<<"++++++++call three_step_coroutine first++++++++"<<std::endl;
    auto val = co_await future;
    std::cout<<"++++++++call three_step_coroutine second++++++++, val: "<<val<<std::endl;
    val = co_await future; 
    std::cout<<"++++++++call three_step_coroutine third++++++++, val: "<<val<<std::endl;
    val = co_await future; 
    std::cout<<"++++++++call three_step_coroutine end++++++++, val: "<<val<<std::endl;
    co_return;
}
int main(){
    auto ret = call_coroutine();
    std::cout<<"++++++++begine call_coroutine resume in main++++++++"<<std::endl;
    ret.resume();
    std::cout<<"++++++++end call_coroutine resume in main++++++++"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
promise_type constructor void
get_return_object void
initial_suspend void
void_future constructor
++++++++begine call_coroutine resume in main++++++++
promise_type constructor
get_return_object
initial_suspend
future_type constructor
++++++++call three_step_coroutine first++++++++
three_step_coroutine begin
yield_value : 222
++++++++call three_step_coroutine second++++++++, val: 222
three_step_coroutine running
yield_value : 333
++++++++call three_step_coroutine third++++++++, val: 333
three_step_coroutine end
return_value : 444
final_suspend
promise_type destructor
++++++++call three_step_coroutine end++++++++, val: 444
return_void void: 
future_type destructor
```

The problem is: the main function is not finished,the last message of “++++++++end call_coroutine resume in main++++++++” is not printed, while the "call_coroutine" is finished, what should I do ....

Thanks.

Comment: The program exited with code 139, which is "segmentation violation", probably due to UB. A coroutine ends with `co_await final_suspend(); coroutine_handle.destroy();` Since your `final_suspend` is `suspend_never`, the `co_await final_suspend()` returns, and then the coroutine handle is destroyed. You then destroy it a second time in the `future_type` destructor, which is a double-free, therefore UB.

Comment: Thanks! It is just as you said! I remove the destroy operation and the problem solved!